# How can I make my WhatsApp icons in JavaScript visible again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, whatsapp

I have had the website for 3 years. This website is created by HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I have made it by myself and there is always a WhatsApp icon at the bottom of the right. But 6 months ago, it disappeared. I looked up my code and there are no changes. How can I make my WhatsApp ıcon visible again?

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
        whatsapp: "+9000000000", // Contact Number
        call_to_action: "Merhaba, Size nasıl yardımcı olabilirim?",
        position: "right", 
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
        })();
    
    //</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain `whatshelp.io` is currently timing out, which is probably why the buttons are not working.

Based on `archive.org`, it appears at some point the site started to redirect to `bothelp.io`. However, updating the script to `https://static.bothelp.io/widget-send-button/js/init.js` returns a 404.

After some googling, I landed on this page: `https://apps.shopify.com/whatshelp-chat-button`

The description noted the following:

> The GetButton widget (former WhatsHelp widget) takes website visitor directly...

Again, updated the script to `https://static.getbutton.io/widget/bundle.js` and success!

I then updated the configuration script you provided to the following (formatted for legibility):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var options = {
                whatsapp: "+9000000000", // Contact Number
                call_to_action: "Merhaba, Size nasıl yardımcı olabilirim?",
                position: "right", 
            };
            var proto = document.location.protocol,
                host = "getbutton.io",
                url = proto + "//static." + host;
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
            s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
            
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);    
        })();
    </script>
```

And saw the following:

[image: rendered]